# Infinite connected graph such that every vertex has finite degree

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an connected graph with $|V| \geq \aleph_0$ such that $\text{deg}(v)$ is finite for all $v\in V$.

Does this imply that $|V|=\aleph_0$?

Comment: Sounds about right. Pick a vertex $v$ and consider the number of vertices that can be reached from $v$ in up to $n$ steps. (I assume a connected infinite graph is one in which any two vertices have a path of *finite* length between them.)

Comment: That's the answer...! Could you post this not as comment, but as answer? Thx

Comment: @Rahul:  Your Comment was invited to be posted as an Answer.  I think it would make a good one, perhaps with a little elaboration when you find the time.